# How to update the empty Pandas dataframe from the the sum of the bottom x rows of a column from an another Pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to sum the bottom x rows of each column of the dataframe and update it in a another empty data frame.

I tried the below code but i could not update the dataframe.

The master DataFrame is ‘df_new_final’ and it contains numerical values.
I want to update in a ‘df_new_final_tail’ as an input of the sum of tail 15 rows from Master DataFrame. But df_new_final_tail is still an empty but i can see that ‘sum_x’ is getting calculated. Not sure why it is not getting updated.

```
Master DataFrame ——> df_new_final
Child DataFrame ——-> df_new_final_tail

df_series_list = df_series.columns.values.tolist() 
df_new_final_tail = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_series_list)

for items in df_series_list:
    sum_x = df_new_final.tail(15)[items+’_buy’].sum()
    df_new_final_tail[items]=sum_x
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert `Series` after `sum` to one column `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and for one row `DataFrame` use transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
df_new_final_tail = df_new_final.tail(15).sum().to_frame().T
```

If `df_series` is another `DataFrame` and columns names are same with suffix `_buy` for parse `df_new_final` use:

```
items = df_series.columns
df_new_final_tail = df_new_final.tail(15)[items+'_buy'].sum().to_frame().T
```

Comment: nice! simpler than calling `DataFrame`